# Get Pixel Color From Kinect Depth Stream

Tags: colors, kinect, pixel, kinect-sdk

I am currently having a bit of difficulty trying to find the color of a specific pixel from a Kinect Depth Stream.  The code below is what I am using to calculate the color of the pixel at (100, 100).

I have a feeling that my logic is flawed somewhere (perhaps when calculating the index into colorPixels that I want)

colorPixels and depthPixels are declared as follows:

```
colorFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(colorPixels); //colorPixels is a byte[]
depthFrame.CopyDepthImagePixelDataTo(depthPixels); //depthPixels is a DepthImagePixel[]
```

I calculate the rgb value of the pixel at 100,100 in the depth stream as follows:

```
DepthImagePoint ballDepthPoint = new DepthImagePoint();
int ballPosX = 100;
int ballPosY = 100;
int blueTotal = 0, greenTotal = 0, redTotal = 0;

ColorImagePoint ballColorPoint;

//build a depth point to translate to a color point
ballDepthPoint.X = ballPosX;
ballDepthPoint.Y = ballPosY;
ballDepthPoint.Depth = this.depthPixels[ballDepthPoint.X * ballDepthPoint.Y].Depth;

//work out the point on the color image from this depth point
ballColorPoint = this.sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapDepthPointToColorPoint(this.sensor.DepthStream.Format, ballDepthPoint, this.sensor.ColorStream.Format);

//extract the rgb values form the color pixels array
blueTotal += (int)colorPixels[(ballColorPoint.X * ballColorPoint.Y * colorFrame.BytesPerPixel)];
greenTotal += (int)colorPixels[(ballColorPoint.X * ballColorPoint.Y * colorFrame.BytesPerPixel) + 1];
redTotal += (int)colorPixels[(ballColorPoint.X * ballColorPoint.Y * colorFrame.BytesPerPixel) + 2];

System.Console.WriteLine("The ball found is " + redTotal + "," + blueTotal + "," + greenTotal + " which is " + Helper.ColorChooser(redTotal, greenTotal, blueTotal));
```

The ColorChooser method is as follows:

```
public static String ColorChooser(int r, int g, int b)
    {

        if (r >= g && r >= b)
        {
            return "RED";
        }
        else if (b >= g && b >= r)
        {
            return "BLUE";
        }
        else
            return "GREEN";
    }
```

If you need any more information/code let me know.

Many Thanks,

Dave McB

Comment: Hey Dave, what are you using to read the depth data stream in the first place? I would assume proprietary microsoft tools but I wanted to find out for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Got there in the end, the correct way to index the pixel in the color pixels seems to be:

```
colorPixels[(ballColorPoint.X * colorFrame.BytesPerPixel) + (ballColorPoint.Y * stride)];
```

where:

```
int stride = colorFrame.BytesPerPixel * colorFrame.Width;
```

Comment: Was this an example in a Kinect programming book? I think I have seen it before.